# Why can't I write Nullable<Nullable<int>>?

Tags: c#, nullable, value-type

The definition of [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) is:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct, new()
```

The constraint `where T : struct` implies that `T` can only be a value type. So I very well understand that I cannot write:

```
Nullable<string> a; //error. makes sense to me
```

Because `string` is a reference type, not a value type. But I don't really understand why can't I write

```
Nullable<Nullable<int>> b; //error. but why?
```

Why is it not allowed? After all, `Nullable<int>` is a value-type, and therefore, it can be type argument to `Nullablle<T>`.

When I compiled it on ideone, it gives this error ([ideone](http://ideone.com/v1uoO)):

> error CS0453: The type 'int?' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'
>   Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

Comment: Sorry, my answer is wrong. The statement `new Nullable<int>();` compiles (resulting in an `int?` with a value of null), although the default constructor isn't documented.

Comment: And yes, the answer is in the error that you should get when you try to compile your code.

Comment: @rudolf_franek: whatever that means, but my focus is on the type constraint, not on the semantic mean of the code.

Comment: @rudolf_franek: As I said, I'm focusing on the constraint type, according to which the code should compile, even if it semantically doesn't make sense.

Comment: @rudolf_franek: Sorry. your comments don't help in understanding the language here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From section 4.1.10 of the C# language spec:

> A ***non-nullable value type*** conversely is any value type other than `System.Nullable<T>` and its shorthand `T?` (for any `T`), plus any type parameter that is constrained to be a non-nullable value type (that is, any type parameter with a `struct` constraint). The `System.Nullable<T>` type specifies the value type constraint for `T` (§10.1.5), which means that the underlying type of a nullable type can be any non-nullable value type. The underlying type of a nullable type cannot be a nullable type or a reference type. For example, `int??` and `string?` are invalid types.

Answer (score 10):

Because it's in the C# spec (section 4.4.4):

> If the constraint is the value type constraint (struct), the type A must satisfy one of the following:
>
> - A is a struct type or enum type, *but not a nullable type*. Note that System.ValueType and System.Enum are reference types that do not satisfy this constraint.
> - A is a type parameter having the value type constraint (§10.1.5).

Comment: Please expand on the spec quotation. I didn't completely understand that. I'm new to C#.

Comment: The `struct` generic type constraint you apply to classes is _specified_ as meaning 'all value & enum types apart from `Nullable<T>`', specifically to stop this circularity.

Comment: @thecoop: It's not a singularity.  Were it not for the `struct` constraint on `Nullable`'s type parameter, one could usefully have a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` include a method `Nullable<TValue> `TryGetValue(TKey)` without having to use an `out` parameter.  Given `Dictionary<String, Nullable<int>> myDict`, after `var it=myDict.TryGetValue("Fred");` if `it.HasValue` was false, that would mean no key was found; if `it.HasValue` was true but `it.Value.HasValue` was false, that would mean a null value was stored for key "Fred".  The real difficulty stems from MS's decision to have...

Comment: ...a default-valued `Nullable<T>` box as null rather than as a default-valued `Nullable<T>`, which makes different kinds of empty nullables indistinguishable.

Answer (score 4):

From §10.1.5 of the C# 4 spec:

> The value type constraint specifies that a type argument used for the type parameter must be a non-nullable value type. All non-nullable struct types, enum types, and type parameters having the value type constraint satisfy this constraint. Note that although classified as a value type, a nullable type (§4.1.10) does not satisfy the value type constraint. A type parameter having the value type constraint cannot also have the constructor-constraint.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, the spec prohibits this.

Digging deeper, it's worth realising that you *can* make your own struct that allows this pattern:

```
struct Nestable<T> where T : struct { /* ... */ }

new Nestable<Nestable<int>>(); // This works just fine
```

The prohibition of nested nullables can not be expressed using the type system available to you and me. It is only enforced by a special case in the compiler (CS0453).

---

*Aside:* The `new()` constraint shown in the question doesn't actually exist on `System.Nullable<T>`. `new()` constraints are prohibited when using the `struct` constraint.

> CS0451: The 'new()' constraint cannot be used with the 'struct' constraint

All structs support default initialisation anyway.

Comment: According to the docs, there is no longer a `new()` constraint: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly an answer, but just food for thought.

**Round 1**

`Nullable<Nullable<int>> a;`

> error CS0453: The type 'int?' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable'

Intellisense hints...
*The name can be simplified*

---

**Round 2**

`Nullable<int?>` a;

> error CS0453: The type 'int?' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable'

Intellisense hints...
*The name can be simplified*

---

**Round 3**

`int?? a;`

> error CS1519: Invalid token '??' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
>
> error CS1525: Invalid expression term '??'

---

**Conclusion**

`int?` is essentially just a short-hand evaluation of `Nullable<int>`, but there's no such thing as `int??` which is the only way I can see of representing `Nullable<Nullable<int>>` in short-hand. Plus `int??` borrows the null-coalescing operator, so I'm glad it's not possible because it looks dreadful. *Imagine `int????????????? a;`* How pointless.

Finally, since the reference source for [Nullable](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs) does not yield any constraints for enforcing this, my guess is that this constraint was baked into the CLR as a special case when nullable value types were introduced into C#.