# Why is Nullable<T> nullable? Why it cannot be reproduced?

Tags: c#, nullable

When I write

`Nullable<Nullable<DateTime>> test = null;`

I get a compilation error:

`The type 'System.Datetime?' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as a paramreter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>'`

But `Nullable<T>` is a `struct` so it's supposed to be non-nullable.

So I tried to create this `struct`:

```
public struct Foo<T> where T : struct
{
    private T value;

    public Foo(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static explicit operator Foo<T>(T? value)
    {
        return new Foo<T>(value.Value);
    }

    public static implicit operator T?(Foo<T> value)
    {
        return new Nullable<T>(value.value);
    }
}
```

Now when I write

```
        Nullable<Foo<DateTime>> test1 = null;
        Foo<Nullable<DateTime>> test2 = null;
        Foo<DateTime> test3 = null;
```

The first line is ok but for the second and third lines I get the two following compilation error:

`The type 'System.DateTime?' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as a parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'MyProject.Foo<T>'` (second line only)

and

`Cannot convert null to 'MyProject.Foo<System.DateTime?> because it is a non-nullable value type'`

```
        Foo<Nullable<DateTime>> test = new Foo<DateTime?>();
```

doesn't work neither event if `Nullable<DateTime>` is a `struct`.

Conceptually, I can understand why `Nullable<T>` is nullable, it avoids having stuffs like `DateTime??????????` however I can still have `List<List<List<List<List<DateTime>>>>>`...

So why this limitation and why can't I reproduce this behavior in `Foo<T>`? Is this limitation enforced by the compiler or is it intrinsic in `Nullable<T>` code?

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597218/why-cant-i-write-nullablenullableint) but it just says that it is not possible none of the answers say fundamentally why it's not possible.

Comment: Maybe to pass Nullable<DateTime> to Foo<T> you must put Foo<T?> The error is just telling you that DateTime? can not be a parameter to pass for T because T is non-nullable. If T is refering a non-nullable type Nullable<DateTime> is nullable and won't fit never in that declaration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But Nullable is a struct so it's supposed to be non-nullable.

`Nullable<T>` is indeed a struct, but the precise meaning of the generic `struct` constraint as stated in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) is:

> The type argument must be a value type. Any value type except [`Nullable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.aspx) can be specified. See [Using Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) for more information.

For the same reason, your line

```
Foo<Nullable<DateTime>> test2 = null;
```

results in the compiler error you are seeing, because your generic `struct` constraint restricts your generic `T` argument in a way so `Nullable<DateTime>` must not be specified as an actual argument.

A rationale for this may have been to make calls such as

```
Nullable<Nullable<DateTime>> test = null;
```

less ambiguous: Does that mean you want to set `test.HasValue` to `false`, or do you actually want to set `test.HasValue` to `true` and `test.Value.HasValue` to `false`? With the given restriction to non-nullable type arguments, this confusion does not occur.

Lastly, the `null` assignment works with `Nullable<T>` because - as implied by the selected answers and their comments to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867088/how-clr-can-bypass-throwing-error-when-assigning-a-null-value-to-the-struct) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865604/where-in-memory-are-nullable-types-stored) - the `Nullable<T>` type is supported by some compiler magic.

Comment: It might be helpful to elaborate on that compiler magic, like how a struct is assignable and comparable to null.

Comment: What I am interested in is indeed that compiler magic. How does it work, and what makes this non-reproducible.

Comment: @Guillaume: Well, I presume it's non-reproducible because it's hard-coded in the compiler to apply that magic to `System.Nullable<T>` and to nothing else. As for how it works, you might want to have a look into the source code of Mono's C# compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that the type-parameter of Nullable should be not-nullable.

What you're doing, is creating a Nullable type which has a nullable type-parameter, which is not allowed:

```
Nullable<Nullable<DateTime>>
```

is the same as

```
Nullable<DateTime?>
```

Which is quite pointless.  Why do you want to have a nullable type for a type that is already nullable ?

Nullable is just a type that has been introduced in .NET 2.0 so that you are able to use ' nullable value types'.  For instance, if you have a method wich has a datetime-parameter that is optional; instead of passing a 'magic value' like DateTime.MinValue, you can now pass null to that method if you do not want to use that parameter.

Comment: Hm it might not make sense but `0 + 0` does not make sense either. It is a valid program. I think the OP wants to know if there are more fundamental reasons why it was explicitly disallowed.

Comment: Were it not for the `struct` constraint, something like `Nullable<T>` would be a logical return type for a something like a `Dictionary<string, T>` to have for its `TryGetValue` method, especially if `Nullable<T>` were a simple exposed-field struct without all its special quirks.  After `foo=MyDict["George"]`, if `foo.HasValue` were false, that would mean the key was not found. If `foo.HasValue` were true, that would mean that `Foo.Value` would hold the value associated with key.  Even if `foo.Value` represented a null, that would be usefully distinct from "key not found".

Answer (score 1):

In generic classes `where T: struct` means that type `T` cannot be null.
However Nullable types are designed to add nullability to structs. Technically they are structs, but they behave like they may contain null value. Because of this ambiguity the use of nullables is not allowed with `where T: struct` constraint - see [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Nullable types are not just generic structs with special C# compiler support. Nullable types are supported by CLR itself (see CLR via C# by Jeffrey Richter), and looks like this special CLR support makes them non-recursive.

- CLR supports special boxing/unboxing rules `int? i = 1; object o = i` will put `int` value into variable `o` and not `Nullable<int>` value. In case of multiple nullables - should `o = (int??)1;` contain `int` or `int?` value?
- CLR has special support for calling GetType and interface members - it calls methods of underlying type. This actually leads to situation when Nullable.GetType() throws a NullObjectReference exception, when it has NullValueFlag.

As for C#, there are a lot of features in C# that are hard-coded for nullable types.
Based on this article [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the primary goal of introducing nullable types is to add null support for the types that do not support nulls. Logically, since DateTime? already supports nulls it shouldn't be allowed to be "more" nullable.

This document also plainly states that

> Nested nullable types are not allowed. The following line will not compile: `Nullable<Nullable<int>> n;`

Special C# features of nullable types:

- C# has special ?? operator. Should `(int???)null ?? (int)1` resolve to `(int??)1` or to `(int)1` value?
- Nullables have special `System.Nullable.GetValueOrDefault` property. What should it return for nested nullables?
- Special processing for `? == null` and `? != null` operators. If the `Nullable<Nullable<T>>` contains `Nullable<T>` value, but this value is null, what should HasValue property return? What should be the result of comparison with null?
- Special implicit conversions. Should `int?? i = 10` be implicitly convertible?
- Explicit conversions. Should be `int i = (int??)10;` supported?
- Special support for bool? type [Using nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx). E.g. `(bool?)null | (bool?)true == true`.

So, should CLR support recursive GetType() call? Should it remove Nullable wrappers when boxing value? If it should do for one-level values, why don't for all other levels as well? Too many options to consider, too many recursive processing.

The easiest solution is to make `Nullable<Nullable<T>>` non-compilable.

Comment: Nah... The easiest solution would have been not to define the nullable concept as a struct at all, but rather as a boxed value type, which naturally permits null with fewer special cases in the CLR and compiler. Great explanation though! Best answer here.

Comment: @Qwertie: Another alternative would be to require the default value for a `Nullable<T>` be referred to as `Nullable<T>.Null` rather than just `null`, and have a `Nullable<T>` box as a `Nullable<T>` (whose `HasValue` may be true or false).  Allow a `T` or `Nullable<T>` to be unboxed from a boxed `T` or `Nullable<T>`, except that unboxing `Nullable<T>` as `T` would throw an exception if `HasValue` is false.  Under such rules, there would be no need for the `struct` constraint on `T`.