# Nullable<int?> is not possible, Why not?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, nullable, internals

Excuse me if its a silly question, I am trying to get a better understanding of Nullable types in .Net.

From what i notice from Microsoft source code (using ReSharper), I understand that Nullable is a struct and T needs to be a struct

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
```

Now, I tried to do something like this

```
public struct CustomNullable<T> where T : struct
{
}
public class CustomNullableClass<T> where T : struct
{
}
```

And I get an error when I compile:

```
  Nullable<int?> a = null;
  Nullable<Nullable<int>> a1 = null;
```

For the above mentioned code I get an error 'Only non-nullable value types could be underlying of System.Nullable', but how is this enforced in the Nullable type ?

And for

```
   CustomNullable<int?> a2 = null;
   CustomNullableClass<int?> a3 = null;
```

I get an error 'The type System.Nullable must be non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter T '.

I am bit confused now, can some one help me understand whats going on or have I not understood something ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT: 
If structs are value types and value types can't be null, how can a Nullable be a struct?

Credit : spender

Comment: I'm sure there is a duplicate but I can't find it. Edit: done!

Comment: Why do you want a nullable nullable type?

Comment: Wouldn't a better question be, if structs are value types and value types can't be null, how can a `Nullable` be a struct?

Comment: I dont want to make a nullable nullable type, I am just trying to understand, playing about really

Comment: See here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476590/why-is-nullablet-nullable-why-it-cannot-be-reproduced?rq=1

Comment: @spender Actually, `Nullable` isn't really capable of being `null`, it "just" has a special state that when compared to `null` produces `true`. This is nicely evident through the fact that on a `null` `Nullable` you can still retrieve the property `HasValue`. Interestingly, once you *box* the nullable `null` value, it becomes *actual* `null` and calling any method on that results in `NullReferenceException` - yet another hack in the type system (comment in reference source: `we have special type system support that says a a boxed Nullable<T> can be used where a boxed<T> is used`).

Comment: @Luuaan: I knew that, but it seemed like a pertinent question to get the OP to question more about the magical qualities of a `Nullable`. Thanks for stepping up to the mark :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, it's an internal hack somewhere in the C# compiler (guessing). You cannot replicate it in your own classes. If you make your own type, using the exact same IL, it will *not* enforce that additional hidden constraint.

Answer (score 4):

There is special compiler support specifically for `Nullable`.  You're not capable of reproducing a number of different possible behaviors of `Nullable` with a custom struct.  One of those behaviors is the one that you've mentioned here, that `Nullable` doesn't meet the generic constraint for a `struct` despite being a `struct`.